# How to find out the revision number of fluent nhibernate's source code from where 1.0RTM was created

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm currently building a new app and am stuck on the following 2 issues:

1. I wanted to check-out the tag/revision from the repo of fluent nhibernate from which 1.0RTM was created.But even after looking through the directory structure, I couldn't figure out which one was that.(Its pretty simple for NHibernate though, since they have a tags folder with the periodically released tags).
2. The other thing where I'm struggling is even finding the repo for NHibernate.Linq's source.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction for both of these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluent NHibernate is hosted on github, and there's a tag for each release. For example: [release-1.0RTM](http://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/tree/release-1.0RTM).

NHibernate.Linq is unrelated to Fluent NHibernate, it's a part of [NHContrib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/).

Comment: Thanks a lot James!! Wondering though, is subversion able to read git structure?

Comment: No, it isn't. You need to install Git to use a Git repository. Fluent NHibernate does have a mirroed SVN repository, if you need it. http://code.google.com/p/fluent-nhibernate/source

Comment: Yes.Actually I was trying out on the google repo when I asked the question, since there isn't a release folder anywhere there.